# How much space does Blender take up on a computer?

Tags: performance

I've been considering downloading Blender, but am unsure how much space it'll take up on my computer's memory.  Thanks to anyone who can help answer this question!

Comment: It depends greatly on what you're doing in Blender. As long as you have 1Gb of available memory, it should be fine for most cases.

Comment: Blender recommends minimum of 2 GB system memory. It recommends at least 8 GB of memory for average use. https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: The installation is around 300MB

Comment: Yes, after extraction/installation a default Windows Blender installation should be anywhere between 290 and 300Mb aproximately. But then again if your hard drive is so full that 300Mb cause trouble, then you should probably be doing some cleanup maintenance to your computer in the first place anyway, and perhaps uninstall uneeded stuff and archive old documents

Answer (score 3):

Taken from https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Blender 2.66a - Needs about 186Mb of harddrive space
Blender 2.78b - Needs about 330Mb of harddrive space
Blender 2.83< - Needs about 395Mb of harddrive space

**Minimum (basic usage) hardware**
32-bit dual core 2Ghz
CPU with SSE2 support.
2 GB RAM Physical Ram
24 bits 1280×768 display
Mouse or trackpad
OpenGL 2.1 compatible graphics with 512 MB RAM

**Recommended hardware**
64-bit quad core CPU
8 GB RAM Physical Ram
Full HD display with 24 bit color
Three button mouse
OpenGL 3.2 compatible graphics with 2 GB RAM

**Optimal (production-grade) hardware**
64-bit eight core CPU
16 GB RAM Physical Ram
Two full HD displays with 24 bit color
Three button mouse and graphics tablet
Dual OpenGL 3.2 compatible graphics cards with 4 GB RAM

**For Your reference My Production system Built...**
Windows 10 64bit
Asus COG8580 i73770K 3.5GHz 4 Core 8 Logical Processor
16GB Ram Physical Ram
2 X Eizo Screens
Basic 3 button wired Logitech mouse
Nvidia GTX970 + Nvidia GTX680 (Dual Graphics)
2 X Solid state drives 260GB + 120GB
1 X SATA 1TB drive

For learning purposes blender should run just fine with any system that isn't too old to begin with. If you are having problem I do suggest installing an earlier build since those versions are less intensive and a learning tool before investing on a more appropriate system.