# Blender won't open correctly

Tags: python, error

I'm going to be real blunt here I don't have much to go on about but everytime I open blender I get a little lag from the application then a window in python opens up with the following text show in the picture below anyone have an Idea what's going on with my blender app the program won't respond I don't know what to do[image]?

Comment: Spare us more information so we could help you. Example the version of blender you are using, your system specifications ... windows 10 64bit ... ram and build, etc... Also where did you get the version of blender, did you happen to download it off a unofficial website?

Comment: Some basic specification requirements to run blender here. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75888/how-much-space-does-blender-take-up-on-a-computer/75899#75899